# Bitlocker encrypted drive 8.1

Tags: windows, laptop, windows-8.1, laptop-repair

*-EDIT* - in DISKPART - Volume 0 is my C drive. It's blank under 'LABEL'. The file system is 'UNKNOWN'. Wouldn't that mean it's corrupted? What can I do about this?

First off, I'd like to say I've never even heard of bitlocker before and I definitely did NOT set it up on my computer.

My computer will not properly boot. It loops saying it had a CRITICAL_SERVICE_FAILED error.
When it loads to the repair screen, it asks for a bitlocker password because my drive is locked.

I can try to troubleshoot through the CMD, and I have no access to my C: drive because it's locked. I have files I need for school that have not been backed up. Please help.

What is the point of the recovery key ID when it tells me to go to http://windows.microsoft.com/recoverykeyfaq .    This does not tell me anything helpful that I can find.

Comment: Something has encrypted your data in such a way that it appears that it was encrypted by Bitlocker.  This isn't the first question this week that described this problem, I am going to guess, its a new malware vector.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion as to how I deal with this malware? I can get into CMD and execute commands.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that 'somehow' your drive has become encrypted. Does anyone other than you have access to your computer?

Unfortunately, it is not simple to repair or fix this issue. As it seems that the entire drive is encrypted, it is not simply possible to regain the data without the original encryption key. As you can't recall setting this up, the last resort would be to check your Microsoft account (if you have that set up for your laptop) for encryption keys here.

https://onedrive.live.com/recoverykey

Comment: No one has access to the computer. I actually was working on my paper last night, went to bed, woke up and now I cannot get back into my computer.

Comment: HDDs are not encrypted by themselfs.  It might not be local access could be remote.

Comment: You also might want to try to mount it using a Linux computer.

Comment: @Ramhound in Windows 8.1 drives get encrypted automatically when you use a Microsoft account to login. Brett must follow the link on a second device, logon with his MS account/Live ID to get the bitlocker key.